# dynamic routing for images in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a big deal with image or some features routing in laravel ... for example I have a dashboard page that has @yield('content') ... in dashboard there are some images like logo.png / background-pattern.png & ... . when I get a url for them for example

```
src="assets/img/logo.png"
```

. it's ok for urls like

```
Route::get('/reports' ...)
```

but it doesnt work for

```
Route::get('/report/crete' ...)
```

page . for create page I should give a src like

```
 src="../assets/img/logo.png"
```

how can I give the url dynamically to images ??

sorry if it's stupid question I'm newbie in laravel .
thanks for time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
asset('assets/img/logo.png')
```

It will generate the whole url.

Another method is setting base href in head section of your HTML document:

```
<base href="http://yoururl.com/" />
```

(with trailing slash at the end)

and use everywhere:

```
src="assets/img/logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule use absolute paths:

```
src="/assets/whatever"
```

then it doesn't matter if the url contains 'directory', like `/some/roue/here`

Using helper `asset` provided by laravel is also the way of course.