# Parameter in Route::get caused style to disappear?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, parameter-passing, laravel-routing

I'm still new to Laravel. Anyway, I'm making a small system of viewing and creating articles to be shown in the main site. I wanted to create a page that displays an article from the database, using a parameter from the URL, like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/read/1
```

The above, for example, will display the article with 'id' value of 1 in the database.

### So it works just fine, but problem is, after I got it to work (which took me some time since I'm a newbie), the whole style just disappears from the page. I tried to rewrite everything but it still didn't work. New pages that I create include the style just fine.

This is my route line:

```
Route::get('read/{id}', array('as' => 'read', 'uses' => 'NewsController@readArticle'));
```

NewsController readArticle function:

```
    public function readArticle($id) {
    $article = NewsMessage::where('id', $id) -> first();

    return View::make('news.read', array('article' => $article));
    }
```

And the file read.blade.php (located in views/news/read.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    {{ $article -> title }}
@stop
```

So the whole PHP code works fine and I manage to get the title. But for some reason, the whole style disappears and this is what I see:

http://puu.sh/ctO6J/db30fbe102.png

So any idea, what have I dont wrong that caused this? The other pages work just fine with the style included.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic routing for images in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319100/dynamic-routing-for-images-in-laravel) - this is exactly the same as in this topic. Use the same for your stylesheet as I answered about images.

Comment: Worked with using asset(). Thank you :)
Didn't find it using the Google search, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the path to the image is incorrectly specified.

You can either use the built in asset methods or something like `{{ URL::to('/')/imagepathhere/filename.jpg }}`

Comment: Actually Marcin's solution seems to make more sense to me. It also made me re-organize my public folder and have an 'assets' folder in it. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your styles links wrote as:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('styles')
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@endsection

@section('content')
    {{ $article -> title }}
@endsection
```

Correct Syntax:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endsection

@section('content')
    {{ $article -> title }}
@endsection
```

And make sure your *css* folder is located at **public** folder when calling with *asset()* helper.

This issues of disappearing the whole page styles is causing by accessing the **image** or **css file** or any other resources, and the solution is to use *asset()* helper function.

NOTE: *YOUR ROUTES AND CONTROLLER HAS NO ISSUE, YOU DON'T NEED TO TOUCH EITHER.*

Answer (score -1):

make sure to insert base tag in head  like this
`<head><base href="/public"></head>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).